# What is the volume and surface area of the 1-Sphere?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I am reading a post on here that mentioned something about the 1-sphere. I know that a 2-sphere is a circle, and 3-sphere is a volume, but what is this 1-sphere and how do you calculate the volume and surface area of a 1-sphere?

Comment: If $n$ is a non-negative integer, the usual definitions are: The _unit $n$-sphere_ is the set $S^{n} = \{x \in \mathbf{R}^{n+1} : \|x\| = 1\}$, and the _unit $(n+1)$-ball_ is $B^{n+1} = \{x \in \mathbf{R}^{n+1} : \|x\| \leq 1\}$. The $n$-sphere has "$n$-volume", and the $(n+1)$-ball has "$(n+1)$-volume". ($1$-volume is "length", $2$-volume is "area", etc. "Area" of an $n$-sphere is meaningless unless $n = 2$.) Could you please formulate your question carefully using these definitions? As is, it's difficult to understand what you're asking. :)

Answer (score 2):

A 2-sphere is a standard sphere, if I understand correctly, because the surface itself is a mapping of a two dimensional space (the plane). The standard way of seeing this is called "stereographic projection" in which the circles sits on top of a place, and lines are drawn from the north pole through the sphere to the plane. This is a correspondence between the points in the plane and the points on the sphere.

The 1-sphere is the image of a function of one-variable, so it is a circle. The typical example is to parameterize it in terms of cosine and sine of a real variable $t$.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of sphere is the set of points equidistant from a center.
$n$-sphere is the sphere in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$. For $n=1$ the sphere is the circle. If, however, you are talking about sphere embedded in one-dimensional space, i.e. a 0-sphere, then it is  the set of two points equidistant from the center.

Since the turn "surface area" is only defined for 2-D  surface, and 0-sphere does not have a 2-d surface, it also does not have "area".

The term "volume" is little more vague, and I think you could say that it is the amount of space enclosed by a figure. In this case the "volume" of a 0-sphere$V=2R$, where $R$ is its radius.

__

**EDIT** Thanks to Alfred Yerger's comment, I have corrected my original answer

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere

Comment: The concepts of "volume" and "surface area" are both well-defined for $3$-dimensional spheres. There definitions can be extended without difficulty to the $n$-dimensional case. Your claim that the $0$-sphere has no "surface" and no "area" is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

For a $0$-dimensional sphere: $V = 1$ and $S = 0$

For a $1$-dimensional sphere: $V = 2R$ and $S = 2$

For a $2$-dimensional sphere: $V = \pi R^2$ and $S = 2\pi R$

For a $3$-dimensional sphere: $V = \frac {4}{3} \pi R^3$ and $S = 4 \pi R^2$

Note that the derivative of the volume with respect to $R$ equals the surface area. This is true for spheres of every dimension $N$.

Comment: I don't believe this adheres with the common convention on what an $n$-sphere is

Comment: @TylerHG I have tried to answer the OP's question. Other posters can discuss the $n$-sphere convention.

Comment: @m.wind Suppose we are talking about the n-sphere convention, then the 0-dimensional sphere would be the set {-1, 1} am I correct? From this detail, how would you come up with the surface area and the volume? Thanks!

Comment: $0$-dimensional space consists of a single point -- the origin ! A sphere of arbitrary radius therefore must have volume $1$. Its surface must be $0$. Of course, purely geometric considerations fail at this level of abstraction. It is actually better to reason on the basis of mathematical definitions and properties.